# How to handle 'Bad Request' on Landing Page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, landing-page

I am running few SQL queries on Landing Page using SSJS, but unfortunately having 'Bad Request' (perhaps time out) most of the times. Please suggest the way forward.
Scenario: After Query.Perform() on Landing Page, I am checking whether the records are loaded into the target DE or not by doing DataExtension.Rows.Retrieve() in DO-While LOOP. If we retrieve DE Rows greater than zero, then proceeding on next step outside the loop.

Thanks,
Gaurav

Comment: By 'Bad request' you mean, while clicking the preview button the page keep on loading? Also, please share some sample code if you can

Comment: Yes, page keep on loading most of the times. Sample code:        var status = QueryDefinition.Add(queryDef);
     }
     var qd = QueryDefinition.Init("QueryDefCustomerKey");
     var status = qd.Perform();
 
     var Condition = "TRUE";
        
     do {
      var TargetDE = DataExtension.Init("DataExtensionName");
      var filter = {Property:"DEName",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:DEval};
      var Rows = TargetDE.Rows.Retrieve(filter); 
      if(Rows.length > 0){
      Condition = "FALSE";
      }
      } while (Condition == "TRUE") .... After this NEXT STEPS

Comment: If that is the case, it means there are errors in your code. Try debugging by using <script> try{ //your code} catch(e) { Write(Stringify(e)); } </script> or divide it part by part and use Write(variablename); to check for correct output.